# Run integration test suite with maven

Tags: junit, test-suite

I'm trying to find a way to run a single integration test suit with maven.

I have a suite defined like that:

```
@RunWith(Suite.class)
@Suite.SuiteClasses({
    ITest1.class,
    ITest2.class,
 })
 public class TestSuitIT {}
```

I try to tun it with the command

```
mvn -Dskip.unit.tests -Dit.test=TestSuitIT integration-test
```

But it doesn't run the suit. I also tried with the full package.

[image]

It does work if I run a single test, but not with the suite. Is it even supported?